# How to convert a condition string to a boolean format?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, boolean, conditional-statements

I taught myself C#. I'm stuck on the following. How do I convert a condition string to a boolean format?

```
string ConditionString = "1 > 2";
bool Judgment = Convert.ToBoolean(ConditionString); //Error
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Judgment);
```

Comment: You need a whole compiler running inside your app for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this block of code (in `System.Data` namespace):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
bool judgment = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Compute("1 > 2", null));
```

that give you a result as `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works well. However, conditional strings such as "3>2 && 2>1" or "apple"=="banana" cause an error. Can you solve this problem by any chance..? Thanks once again!

Comment: @JustTemp the code there is not C#, you need to write things differently. Your example would be "3>2 and 2>1" and "'apple'='banana'".

Comment: @JustTemp Your welcome. As @Theraot said, you should use your conditional phrases as And, Or, (etc.). In your case: `"3>2 And 2>1"` for example. Best approach if your input is not in this format, is using `String.Replace` method to change it.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone! The problem seems to have been resolved! Have a nice day :)